# API returning Error 406 when sending files

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm developing my own API to receive files and using Flutter to create the app.

So I'm sending files to and API, using Flutter Dio, and I keep getting error 406.

```
'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path),
```

Turns out, I found out if I add the following line, it works:

```
'file_tar': await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar')),
```

To work, both lines must be on the code.

On PHP web, the same thing, but I couldn't find a workaround.

Funny thing, using the same API on **Postman, and over there it doesn't require this line**, so I guess this might be Flutter Dio encoding the file somehow, requiring the x-tar Content-Type for the file.

Here is the entire Flutter code:

```
var dio = Dio();
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path),
  'file_tar': await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar')),
});
var response = await dio.post(url,
    data: formData,
    options: Options(headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    }), onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
  var progress = (sent / total) * 100;
  log('Progress: $progress %');
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you provide a log from the API showing a request from both the Flutter App and one from Postman?

Comment: `I guess this might be Flutter Dio encoding the file somehow` - my guess would be that Postman is automatically adding the `Content-Type` header, in an attempt to be "helpful".

Comment: Try to use: `dio.post(url, data: formData, options: Options(headers:useOldHeaders, contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,listFormat: ListFormat.multiCompatible))` .It's important to ensure that the server-side code of the API is configured to handle the Accept header correctly and process file uploads accordingly. Properly setting the Accept header in the API request and ensuring that the server-side code is configured to handle it can help resolve the 406 error when sending files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also. It might help you.

```
var dio = Dio();
var formData = FormData();

 formData.files.addAll([
  MapEntry("file", await MultipartFile.fromFile(file)),
   MapEntry("file_tar", await MultipartFile.fromFile(file ,contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar') )),
]);

var response = await dio.post(url,
    data: formData,
    options: Options(headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    }), onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
  var progress = (sent / total) * 100;
  log('Progress: $progress %');
});
```

OR

```
formData.files.addAll([
  MapEntry(
   'file',
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync(file.path,filename: 'upload.test'),
  ),
  MapEntry(
    'file_tar',
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync(file.path,filename: 'upload.test'),
  ),
]);
```

file_tar is your key then its fine. otherwise you can just write files as in the end its creates array of files.

Comment: it's possible that you are `not specifying the content type correctly`. In this case, you may need to modify the PHP code to accept files with the correct content type.It's also worth noting that `Postman may be able to correctly infer the content type for the file based on its extension`, which is why it works without the `x-tar` content type header. However, it's always a good practice to explicitly specify the content type when sending files to ensure that the server can process the request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be content-type issue. Try this code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

// ...

var dio = Dio();
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
    file.path,
    contentType: MediaType('application', 'octet-stream'),
  ),
});
var response = await dio.post(url,
    data: formData,
    options: Options(headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    }), onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
  var progress = (sent / total) * 100;
  print('Progress: $progress %');
});
```